# Let $T \in L(V)$ if $T^2 = 0$ then $(I-T)$ is bijective.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T \in L(V)$ if $T^2 = 0$ then $(I-T)$ is bijective

Injectivity:

$(I-T)(x) = (I-T)(x')$ then applying T,

$TI(x) - TT(x) = TI(x') -TT(x') \rightarrow $ T(x) = T(x'). Here is where I am stuck. Hints appreciated.

Comment: Is V finite dimensional?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi yes

Comment: Hint: $I-T$ is injective if and only if $\text{ker}(I-T) = 0$

Comment: Hint: Use $I+T$

Comment: So you got an injective map between 2 finite dimensional vector spaces. Do you know that the image of a basis under an injective map gives a set of linearly independent vectors?

Answer (score 4):

One way to show that something is bijective is to give an explicit inverse. I'll leave it to you to verify that $I + T$ is the inverse of $I - T$ in this case.

---

One way to see this without just noticing the difference of squares is that *formally*, the inverse of $I - T$ can be written as a geometric series:

$$(I - T)^{-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} T^k = I + T + T^2 + \dots = I + T$$

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation is injective if and only if its kernel contains only the zero vector. In other words, $A$ is injective iff $A(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. This should generally be your first tool for proving linear transformations are injective.

Assume $(I-T)(x) = I(x) - T(x) = 0$; then $T(x) = I(x) = x$, and so $0 = T^2(x) = T(T(x)) = T(x) = x$, so $x = 0$.

Comment: Great thanks :)

Comment: Of course, given the original problem, the last step is to add the sentence "and since $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T\in L(V)$ is injective iff it is bijective."

Comment: @symplectomorphic can you elaborate on that?

Comment: A linear transformation between vector spaces of the same finite dimension is injective iff it's surjective iff it's bijective.

Comment: @JamesDickens: you asked to prove that $I-T$ is bijective. florence has shown only that $I-T$ is injective.